# Camel bindy fixed-lenth file with delimeter

Tags: apache-camel, bindy

I am using camel-bindy in order to create fixed-length files. I am creating the file correct, but I have a new request to separate each field-column with character ";". Thus at the end I need to have a fixed-length file semicolon separated. Do you know if this is possible with camel-bindy?

Next is my model class

```
@FixedLengthRecord(length = 313, paddingChar = ' ')
public class Fastbox {

    @DataField(pos = 1, length = 7, align = "L")
    private String field1;

    @DataField(pos = 2, length = 10, align = "L")
    private String field2;

    @DataField(pos = 3, length = 3, align = "R")
    private Integer field3;

    @DataField(pos = 4, length = 10, align = "L")
    private String field4;
    ...
```

If i try to use something like this

```
@DataField(pos = 1, length = 7, align = "L", delimiter = ";")
```

I am loosing the length. What I mean by that is that if the value is null, length is not taken into consideration and just puts a semicolon. So I am having

```
;field2    fi3field4
```

instead of

```
       ;field2    fi3field4
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try setting that field to a empty value, eg `""` as default

Comment: You mean @DataField(pos = 1, length = 7, align = "L", delimiter = ";", defaultValue = "")

This is not working

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: I am using  2.17.0.redhat-630283

Comment: Can you try with a newer Camel version. Maybe build a little Camel sample or unit test and give it a go on the latest Camel release.

Comment: For support with Red Hat JBoss Fuse you can use the Red Hat Customer Portal to get professional help with their product.